# Calculating the year of a <xsd:dateTime> gives QueryEvaluationException – SPARQL and Protégé 5

Tags: datetime, xsd, sparql, protege

I’ve been trying to calculate the difference between two dates with a SPARQL query in Protégé 5.

However, every attempt I try that uses Date related functions (like `Year()`, `Month()`, `Day()`) does not work.

Simplifying the query to the most basic point in order to see if the functions are working, I’ve tried the following queries

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
SELECT ?result
 WHERE
 {  BIND("2014-05-22T15:44:35.114+01:00"^^xsd:dateTime AS ?begin)
BIND("2015-06-22T15:44:35.114+01:00"^^xsd:dateTime AS ?end)
BIND(?end AS ?result)
 }
```

This works and gives the proper result:

```
"2015-06-22T15:44:35.114+01:00"^^<xsd:dateTime>
```

However, if I add in the last line, the `year()` function

```
BIND(YEAR(?end) AS ?result)
```

instead of the working

```
BIND(?end AS ?result)
```

The following error appears:

```
An error was thrown: org.openrdf.query.QueryEvaluationException: 
Unknown function 'http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#year-from-dateTime'
```

or

```
Unknown function 'http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#month-from-dateTime' 

Unknown function 'http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#day-from-dateTime'
```

if i try the `month()` function and the `day()` function, respectively.

The same error appears again if I add

```
PREFIX fn: <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#>
```

And try

```
BIND(fn:year-from-dateTime(?end) AS ?result)
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `^^` part is wrong. You want `^^xsd:dateTime` (no `<>`)

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected it. However, the functions still give the same exception.